# How do I generate text output using knit_child?

Tags: r, knitr

Running the following fragment using `knitr`:

````
```{r results='asis'}
df=data.frame(x=c('a','b'),y=1:2)
for (n in c('a','b')){
  text='- inlined `r df[df["x"]==n,]["y"]`'
  cat(paste0(knit_child(text=text,quiet=TRUE),'\n'))
}
```
````

I get the output:

---

*y 1 1*

*- inlined 1 y 2 2*

*- inlined 2*

---

How do I correct this to get the desired output:

---

*- inlined 1*

*- inlined 2*

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotted it... double the brackets to get the cell value... Doh!

````
```{r results='asis'}
df=data.frame(x=c('a','b'),y=1:2)
for (n in c('a','b')){
  text='- inlined `r df[df["x"]==n,][["y"]]`'
  cat(paste0(knit_child(text=text,quiet=TRUE),'\n'))
}
```
````